# Retirar um zero à esquerda

Tags: python

Tenho um arquivo que recebo mensalmente que representa as chamadas realizadas durante um mês.

O arquivo possui uma coluna chamada DURACAO nesse formato: 000:00:30, 001:00:48, etc
Eu preciso que esse campo apresente o seguinte formato 00:00:30, 01:00:48, etc porque esse campo representa a duração de uma chamada telefônica realizada.
No meu código após importar o arquivo, eu executo um laço de for em cada linha da coluna para retirar o primeiro zero. Com uma base de dados pequena ele finalizao código, mas com base de dados grande, ele nao consegue finalizar o código.
Porém em todas as vezes, mesmo com a base de dados pequena ou grande, apresenta a mensagem de erro A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Após esse processo de tratamento dessa coluna DURACAO, eu ainda tenho que dividir o arquivo em dois (devido ao tamanho)e salvar os dois arquivos em csv. Alguem consegue me ajudar?

```py
import pandas as pd
 
fatura = pd.read_csv('18500_4509165_0_1.TXT', delimiter=',').drop(columns=['UF','FATURA','DOCUMENTO','LOCAL','C','S','LOCAL-ORIG','CJ-ORIG','SU-ORIG','PAG','LINHA','LOCAL-DEST','LOCAL-DEST.1','DDD-DEST','FONE-DEST','HORA','COD','DESC-RESU-COD','DEGRAU','GRUPO-HOR','PULSOS','CONCESSIONARIA','PERC-ICMS','PERC-IMPOSTO','COD-EMPRESA','PROD','BLQ-PRESTADORA','NOTA-FISCAL','SERIE-NF','VLR-SERVICO-ICMS','VLR-IMPOSTO','DT-VENC','DT-RECEB','DT-FATURA','DT-COBRANCA','DT-NOVO-VENC','DT-CAIXA','DT-CONTA','CLIENTE','NRC'])


for idx in range(len(fatura.DURACAO)):
    fatura.DURACAO[idx] = fatura.DURACAO[idx][1:]
 
 
fatura1 = fatura.iloc[0:537708]
 
fatura2 = fatura.iloc[537708:1075415]
 
 
fatura1.to_csv("resultado.csv", index = False)
fatura2.to_csv("resultado1.csv", index = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apresento abaixo 3 casos:

### 1) TODOS os registros possuem um zero extra

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"DURACAO": ["001:11:11","002:22:22","003:33:33"]})

df["DURACAO"].str[1:]

0    01:11:11
1    02:22:22
2    03:33:33
Name: DURACAO, dtype: object
```

### Alguns com zero extra outros corretos

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"DURACAO": ["001:11:11","02:22:22","003:33:33"]})

df["DURACAO"].apply(lambda x: x[1:] if len(x) == 9 else x)

0    01:11:11
1    02:22:22
2    03:33:33
Name: DURACAO, dtype: object
```

### Contendo NaN

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"DURACAO": ["001:11:11","02:22:22",np.nan]})

df["DURACAO"].fillna("00:00:00").apply(lambda x: x[1:] if len(x) == 9 else x)

0    01:11:11
1    02:22:22
2    00:00:00
Name: DURACAO, dtype: object
```

Para todos os casos acima você pode ter `df["DURACAO"] = expressão`

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Paulo. Eu usei o exemplo 1, pois todos os registros vem com um zero a mais à esquerda. 

O problema está sendo gravar esses registros alterados para o novo arquivo, com as demais colunas.

Comment: Agora consegui resolver graças a sua ajuda usando o seu exemplo 1. Obrigado pela ajuda, foi fundamental.